# How to measure code coverage of e2e testing which written by typescript?

Tags: angular, protractor, code-coverage, remap-istanbul

i have a angular2 project which is using Protractor for e2e testing. The testing file were written in typescript under Jasmine framework.

Is it possible to get the code coverage data from this kind of e2e testing?

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried grunt-protractor-coverage ?
NPM: https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-protractor-coverage

Github: https://github.com/teerapap/grunt-protractor-runner

Comment: Hi Hikaryu, we didn't use the grunt  in the project, but i'll take a look at your refer link. thank you.